# Autocomplete strings beginning with an @ (at sign) with Readline in Ruby

Tags: ruby, readline

Hey guys I've been struggling with autocompletion and readline, if I have an array of options like this:

```
["@lorem", "@ipsum", "#bla", "#meh"]
```

and I'm in the prompt an put the @ (at sign) and press TAB it shows all the options:

```
what do you want? > @[TAB] 
@lorem @ipsum #bla #meh
```

but if I use any other sign it works:

```
what do you want? > #[TAB]
#bla #meh
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
  opts = ["@lorem", "@ipsum", "#bla", "#meh"]
  question = "whatever? > "

  Readline.completion_append_character = " "
  Readline.completion_proc = proc { |s| opts.grep( /^#{Regexp.escape(s)}/ ) }

  while value = Readline.readline(question, true)
      exit if value == 'q'
      puts value.chomp.strip
  end
end
```

Does anybody know how can I make Readline aware of the @'s?

Comment: Can you show us what code you have so far?

Comment: I just updated the post with the code, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the @ sign being included within the list of word break characters recognised by readline.

You can remove the @ sign from the list of word break characters and this will then work.

```
opts = ["@lorem", "@ipsum", "#bla", "#meh"]
question = "whatever? > "

Readline.basic_word_break_characters = 
    Readline.basic_word_break_characters.delete("@")
Readline.completion_append_character = " "
Readline.completion_proc = proc { |s| opts.grep( /^#{Regexp.escape(s)}/ ) } 

while value = Readline.readline(question, true)
    exit if value == 'q'
    puts value.chomp.strip
end
```

And the results of running this were as follows :-

```
whatever? > #(TAB)
#bla  #meh  
whatever? > @(TAB)
@lorem  @ipsum  
whatever? > q
```